# My Android app stops at opening

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

My Android app stops at opening, but Android studio shows no error. Can somebody help please? I'm trying to convert my website into an android app. I'm a little new at this.

Below is a display of my `MainActivity.java` code

```
package com.example.deedat.webtry2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.motivationalscholar.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my `activity_main.xml` code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.deedat.webtry2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Logcat shows this:

01-10 19:26:15.552 17316-17316/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-10 19:26:15.562 17316-17316/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
01-10 19:26:15.793 17316-17316/com.example.deedat.webtry2 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-10 19:26:15.929 17316-17316/com.example.deedat.webtry2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-10 19:26:15.932 17316-17316/com.example.deedat.webtry2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.deedat.webtry2, PID: 17316
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deedat.webtry2/com.example.deedat.webtry2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class uses-permission
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class uses-permission
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class uses-permission
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.uses-permission" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.deedat.webtry2-qFM_P6edDm6em-M-SNtV1g==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
                                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:703)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
01-10 19:26:15.933 17316-17316/com.example.deedat.webtry2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.deedat.webtry2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

My Android app stops at opening, but Android studio shows no error. Can somebody help please? I'm trying to convert my website into an android app. I'm a little new at this.

Comment: And the logcat says...

Comment: While debugging which portion of the code throws exception or causes the application to crash. Can you share those information.

Comment: Yes Soumya, I've added  the messages from Logcat. Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393141/android-studio-logcat

Comment: Thanks, you solved the problem msangel.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate()` method starts like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    ...
}
```

`myWebView.getSettings()` is almost certainly throwing a `NullPointerException`, as you have never initialized `myWebView`. Add this line just after `setContentView()`:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I did that and still having the same problem. Are there any other ways?